# what is the best way to debug android programs?

Tags: android, debugging

Well, I want debugger to point out me on the line number which generates error ? 
If i get null values at runtime, or my service url path does not exit, it does not point me to specific line.

Is there any best way to debug programs in android rather than just tracing values with log cat ?

I am using eclipse IDE for android development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using eclipse, you can use its built-in debugger.

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html

Set some breakpoints in your code and then follow it until it throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

The logcat error stacktrace should give you a line where the error occured if it is possible.

In case you did not know, if you double-click a stacktrace in eclipse logcat, it shows you the line in your file.

You could also check out [ACRA](http://acra.ch/) and [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com) in case you dont want the device to be connected all the time.

Comment: Well I double click, nothing happens. By right clicking, it gives me two option. I am tesing on eclipse emulator.

Comment: i strongly recommend using a real android device

Answer (score 1):

Popular JAVA and Android IDE such as Eclipse and IntelliJ are shipped with built in debugging tools. Both should be good enough for your need